# Count text cells and dates

Tags: excel, if-statement, formulas, countif, array-formulas

I have a row `B` (more specifically `B9:B500`) that contains dates in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm My row `C` (`C9:C500`) contains some text. These are just a few dropdowns like, "cars","bikes","boats".

[image: The table]

I would like excel to retrieve the amount of times that those words are mentioned on specific months only, so for example, this would be the result i wanted:

March
Car = 1

April
Bikes=1
Car=1

July
Boats=1

I was using this formula (for the month of April and only counting the Bikes in that month) but without any sucess, any ideas?

`=IF((MONTH(B9:B13)=4),COUNTIF(C9:C500,Bikes),0)`

Answer (score 0):

The layout is not quite as you indicated but I'd recommend a PivotTable anyway because they are so powerful:

[image: SO18648732 example]

*Edit to add alternative to PivotTable:*

Without a PivotTable, a 'helper column' would come in useful in connection with use of =MONTH():

[image: SO18648732 second example]

(The block in the middle is a PT, the one on the right not.)

ColumnA was chosen as the helper, and contains `=MONTH(B2)` in A2 (and copied down). The formula in K4 is also copied down and across.

Comment: Thanks pnuts, i did look at pivot tables before but i was really looking for a formula to make it "more clean" on my file. Would you know how can i get that result using a formula?